# Facebook SDK 3.1: Unable to reauthorize user for publish_stream in IOS6

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ipad, permissions, authorization

I have a problem to reauthorize a user for publish_stream in IOS6. I am able to get it working  when user first time added the application to Facebook. If the user removed the permission on Facebook application setting "Post on your behave", then I rerun the iPad application the application still can access but it doesn't popup a dialog for publish_stream permission to the user.

This is my code I have written:

```
if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen])
{
    //if ([[[FBSession activeSession]permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] == NSNotFound) {
        [[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil]
                                                     defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                   completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                       [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                           state:session.state
                                                                          error:error
                                                                         success:success failure:failure];
                                                   }];

        return false;
    //}
    //else
    //    return TRUE;
}
else
{

return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos", nil]
                  allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                          switch (state)
                 {
                     case FBSessionStateCreated:
                     case FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:
                     case FBSessionStateOpen:

                          [[FBSession activeSession] reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil]
                                      defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                            [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                state:session.state
                                                                error:error
                                                              success:success
                                                              failure:failure];
                                            }];

                         break;
                  }

         }];

}
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?